# Razor Pages - Call method from base class after all OnGet handlers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I've got a base class (called BmsPageModel) that inherits from PageModel. There's a method in the BmsPageModel that I need to call on every page so a menu can be populated correctly based on permissions.

How can I make every page that inherits from my base class call this method during/after every OnGet handler without typing it by hand in every page?

Comment: You mean calling `base.OnGet` doesn't work you?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do that. Anytime I add an OnGet method to my base class, it complains about having multiple handlers that match and if I have to put base.OnGet() on every page, I might as well call my other method.

Comment: The easiest way is to call the method inside base class constructor, but the drawback is you cannot access any request data in constructor.

Comment: This is the kind of requirement that you would use a global filter for: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/filters

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I love it when I learn something new from a question. Thanks to @MikeBrind's comment and the following links ([Learn Page Filters](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/filters) and the MS doc on [Page Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/filter?view=aspnetcore-2.2)) I can answer this question and update my code.

I also have a base class that sets a global query filter on the DbContext so each user's data is filtered from each other. I have a common method (called PageLoadAsync) that I have to remember to add to each page's OnGet/OnPost methods. Now with an override of the executing methods I can add the following and not have to add the method in each subclass.

```
public async override Task OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(PageHandlerExecutingContext context, PageHandlerExecutionDelegate next) 
{
    await PageLoadAsync();
    await base.OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(context, next);
}
```

If you want to restrict it to just the OnGet method you can do something like the following:

```
public override void OnPageHandlerExecuting(PageHandlerSelectedContext context)
{
    if(context.HandlerMethod.MethodInfo.Name == nameof(OnGet))
    {
        // code placed here will only execute if the OnGet() method has been selected
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad you posted this as an answer! Mike's comment did exactly what I needed as well.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same at the RazorPage level?  I have some default data I need loaded for every razor page and only Async methods are available to fetch the data.  I don't see any overridable method on RazorPage that would allow me to call my async code for every razor page.  I can achieve the same using the methods in your answer, but then all of my models are polluted with extraneous data.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The override method is 'OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync'.

Answer (score 1):

For razor pages (not MVC) under .Net 5 this seems to work ok

```
public async override Task OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(PageHandlerExecutingContext context, PageHandlerExecutionDelegate next) {
    if (context.HandlerMethod.MethodInfo.Name == "OnGet") {
        // code placed here will only execute if the OnGet() method has been selected
    }
    // Triggers the OnGet, OnPost etc on the child / inherited class
    await base.OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(context, next);
}
```